# "ERRO[0002] error waiting for container: context canceled" issue with sshfs plugin

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have two Ubuntu 18.04 servers running. I installed `sshfs` plugin using the command -

```
docker plugin install --grant-all-permissions vieux/sshfs
```

Created a volume -

```
docker volume create --driver vieux/sshfs -o sshcmd=<user>@<ip>:/home/<user>/test -o password=<passsword> sshvolume
```

Now when I'm trying to mount the volume using any method (e.g `docker run --rm -v sshvolume:/test busybox touch /test/boom`), I'm getting this error -

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/plugins/81f1f27082956d94e7f28a862687bec7d52cb25de49ecb43859d1a006710d0ec/propagated-mount/456f85ae480f26df582b897cb955d44e\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/231072.231072/overlay2/ddf7de72af831594b09f7e09d5ff314877d6df22629cde6ae4a7e1e00b16f525/merged\\\" at \\\"/test\\\" caused \\\"stat /var/lib/docker/231072.231072/plugins/81f1f27082956d94e7f28a862687bec7d52cb25de49ecb43859d1a006710d0ec/propagated-mount/456f85ae480f26df582b897cb955d44e: permission denied\\\"\"": unknown.
ERRO[0002] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Does anyone know have any idea about what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the exact reason behind this issue. But, here's how I fixed it (NOT A SOLUTION) -

- I backed up all the necessary volumes, and config files.
- Purged `docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`
- Removed any trailing files/directories (Use `find / -iname docker` to find those)
- Rebooted
- Reinstalled the previous packages
- Restored all my backups

If you still face the issue, try inspecting the files you backed up previously. If anyone knows the exact reason, or has any idea why the error might've surfaced, please let me know.

Again, THIS IS NOT A VIABLE SOLUTION. If anything, it's a workaround.